# Too many Connections in C# using MySQL while uploading CSV file

Tags: c#, mysql, csv

I'd liked to know on how to resolve this kind of ERROR when I'm trying to insert a Data from CSV file into MYSQL database. Below is my Code:

```
while (null != (sLine = __reader.ReadLine()))
{
    while (rexRunOnLine.IsMatch(sLine) && null != (sNextLine = __reader.ReadLine()))
    {
        sLine += "\n" + sNextLine;

        __rowno++;
        string[] values = rexCsvSplitter.Split(sLine);


        billOfMaterials.Allotment_code = values[0];
        billOfMaterials.category_name = values[1];
        billOfMaterials.activity = values[2];
        billOfMaterials.quantity = values[3];
        billOfMaterials.end_unit_quantity = values[4];
        billOfMaterials.unit = values[5];
        billOfMaterials.description = values[6];
        billOfMaterials.unit_cost = values[7];
        billOfMaterials.regular_labor_cost = values[8];
        billOfMaterials.end_unit_labor_cost = values[9];
        billOfMaterials.type = values[10];
        billOfMaterials.batch = int.Parse(values[11]);
        billOfMaterials.AddBillOfMaterials();

        yield return values;
    }

    __reader.Close();
}
```

Here is the ERROR that I encountered:

[Too many Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDJ1A.jpg)

Comment: Ah, old google my friend: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

Comment: @FrankerZ thanks for the quick response. is it okay to change my maximum connection to any value?